# Count Items in a Group in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I have a tablix with the following details:

Apple

Apple

Apple

Mango

Mango

I want to have a subtotal cell having:

Apple: 3

Mango: 2

How to do this without counting the items by id?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of approaches you can use, You can write a query that generates the row count for you - not knowing your data here is an example

```
SELECT Fruit, COUNT(Fruit) AS NoFruits   FROM  (SELECT Fruit     , 1 AS FruitNo     FROM dbo.xxxtblFRUIT) AS a  GROUP BY Fruit
```

Or in SSRS tablix you can create a group and do a count in there.

[image]

[image]

****UPDATED*****
From what I under stand from your data you can add a row group outside your current group and do the count in that.

[image]

[image]

Thats what would be returned.

Comment: Thanks! But the data that I have to count belongs also to a group. So I cannot just make another dataset and show the count per fruit. :(

Comment: I've updated the answer based on what I think you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're still looking for answer to this...

Could you try adding a new table and then using Row Groups to group the data by the values? If we're using the data set from above, you could set the group to "Fruits." You would want your table to have at least two cells, one cell would contain the fruit (Fields!Fruit.Value) and the second cell would have (Count(Fields!SomeOtherColumnInYourDataset.Value). Does this make sense?